# Can't unlock Lockscreen (sddm)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, sddm

After a fresh boot I can login normally using SDDM. When I hit `Ctrl + Alt + L` to lock the screen (or after autologout) I can't login anymore, the SDDM login prompt just blinks.

Currently I've to hit `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, login to console and type `loginctl unlock-session 2` then hit `Ctrl + Alt + F7` to go back to KDE session.

`journalctl | grep sddm` just show the first successful login after boot.

```
Apr 28 17:03:26 workstation sddm[1221]: Session started
Apr 28 17:03:26 workstation sddm-helper[1237]: [PAM] Ended.
Apr 28 17:03:26 workstation sddm[1221]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 11
Apr 28 17:03:26 workstation sddm[1221]: Greeter stopped.
```

I just discover this line (segfault with `ligGL`):

```
Apr 28 17:26:25 workstation kernel: sddm-greeter[12709]: segfault at 7fd793d65518 ip 00007fd78fa5b1fe sp 00007fffe38dd7d0 error 6 in libGL.so.1.2[7fd78f9e5000+ab000]
```

Any ideas how to fix `sddm`?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm getting that, too, and the supposed workaround, besides being a pain, seems to flirt with violation of corporate security policy.

Comment: Nope - I just installed a different linux distribution at that time. Try to switch to a different display manager I think you need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` and choose lightdm or whatever you like. Good luck.

Comment: It was just a brain freeze on my part... Fresh linux install, followed by `apt full-upgrade`, why should I be surprised if `sddm` needs to be restarted before it works properly...